# Joomla find front-end content in back-end

Tags: search, joomla

I have a text in the front-end which I can't locate it in the back-end.

Is there a way to search or to figure it out?

To be more specific there is a text which I wrote it some time ago but I can't find in which component belongs. There are no articles at all and it's not in the component that is assigned to this menu item.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information you've provided there's very little specifics we could provide.  As is, we don't know if the text is in the database, the code or even part of a language definition.  In addition, the text could be the result of your web server being compromised.  If there are ads for Viagra and other stuff skating up this is midst likely the issue.

You can use any flavor MySQL client to search to see if stored in the database.

To search the code, use your IDE search functionality.  If your not using an IDE, download Notepad++ and install, once launched hit  + F to open search utility.  There is a tab to search all files from a specific directory root, use this to search for the text.

Although the search will find a language override, you should not edit core files, but there is a tool to override core language definitions in Joomla's backend.

Good luck!